# Issue when initiating RStudio - R Session Disconnected

Tags: r, rstudio

Out of the blue I started getting a "R Session Disconnected" message when opening the RStudio and even pressing the botton for Reconnect the following is a "R Session Aborted" error message followed by a new initiation of RStudio which enters in this loop of Session Disconnected.

In that first message, there is some indicative that "this browser was disconnected from the R because another browser connected". I did not make any change in my enviroment to justify such error. Already desinstalled and installed R and RStudio and those errors continue.

I´m using OneDrive to store some files, I don´t know if this may be associated with the problem but even in OneDrive I did not change anything that could be associated with.

Comment: I too am getting this error, using some one drives. Did you find a fix?